# How to redirect custom subdomain of a domain to a single kubernetes service with subdomain as parameter/ path?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a requirement for a multitenant application where each tenant should be separated by sub domains like below

```
t1.example.com  
t2.example.com  
t3.example.com  
.  
.  
.  
tn.example.com
```

So there could be any number of tenants in this case.  I have a Kubernetes Backend Service named **myservice** responsible for handling all those requests and they need to be identified based on their subdomain.
e.g. if the request comes from tn.example.com then it needs to be redirected to the ->  **myservice/tn** .

```
t2.example.com   -> myservice/t2  
t3.example.com   -> myservice/t3 and so on.
```

So here the subdomain name will be the path argument during redirection which will differentiate different subdomains from app perspective . I need to do this dynamically for any number of subdomains.
How this can be achieved in Kubernetes Nginx ingress controller ?

Comment: ITs your local env or cloud env? Option to manually edit Ingress YAML is not an option here? Those subdomains will only increase or also decrease?

Comment: it is on cloud and do not want to manually edit the ingress yaml each time a new tenant is added . subdomain will normally increase. how this would be different if it is an on-premise set up ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) cannot provide exactly what you need in easy and straightforward way.
However, you can always use more advance features, like overriding `Server/Location Block` section with [configuration snippet through annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet), and then use [lua Block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua_block) to extract `subdomain` and change the request URI to backend.

There was similar thread on [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6132), where user `sanigo` used `configuration-snippet` with `lua block` as workaround.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  location ~ ^/v2/ {
    set_by_lua_block $repo {
      local host = ngx.req.get_headers()["host"];
      local reg = "^(?<repo>[^.]+).*";
      local m = ngx.re.match(host, reg);
      return m['repo'];
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/$repo/$1 last;
  }
```

**Quick note:** in this example `<repo>` acts exactly as a `subdomain`.