# kubernetes - route ingress traffic to specific pod for some paths

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have multiple pods, that scale up and down automatically.

I am using an ingress as entry point. I need to route external traffic to a specific pod base on some conditions (lets say path). At the point the request is made I am sure the specific pod is up.

For example lets say I have domain someTest.com, that normally routes traffic to pod 1, 2 and 3 (lets say I identify them by internal ips - 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11 and 192.168.1.13).

When I call someTest.com/specialRequest/12, I need to route the traffic to 192.168.1.12, when I call someTest.com/specialRequest/13, I want to route traffic to 192.168.1.13. For normal cases (someTest.com/normalRequest) I just want to do the lb do his epic job normally.

If pods scale up and 192.168.1.14 appears, I need to be able to call someTest.com/specialRequest/14 and be routed to the mentioned pod.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried with either [session affinity](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#session-affinity) or [sticky sessions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/#sticky-sessions)? Or that won't work in your use case?

Comment: That would fix problems like fallback to polling or connection remake, but no, does not apply in my case, since the second user is using a totally different session.

Comment: Could you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64579378/11977760)? I think this might actually answer your question. As for nginx I dont think so there is easy  way to do that.

Comment: @Jakub At first glance I also thought that may solve my issue... but that is one service with multiple paths. So unless there is a way to send a specific path to a specific pod is not helpful, circling back to the original question, how to route traffic to specific pod, for a specific path :). I actually found a way to add a location block inside the nginx ingress, and set a proxy pass there. Manged to make it work on local but fails in production for some reason. I'll add it as an answer if I manage to make it work :).

Comment: It probably requires a [custom lua plugin](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/plugins) for ingress-nginx. The endpoint data is available as the "backend" in the [balancer](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/ae8c73141396e9dfa62eb815b19b8382908f39e9/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/balancer.lua#L138). Or maybe a new [`balancer_by_lua_block`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#balancer_by_lua_block) that selects backends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of built-in functionality to implement this (if this is what your really want). You can achieve this by building your own [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) for Kubernetes. Your operator may provision a Pod+Ingress combo which will do exactly what you want - forward your traffic to a single pod, or you can provision 2 pods and 1 ingress to achive HA setup.

Depending on the Ingress you are using, it also may be possible to group multiple ingress resources under the same load balancer.

Here is a brief diagram of how this could look like.
[image: example operator]

Comment: I think this is the right answer. I give it one more day then I accept it unless something better appears.

Comment: Hi @zozo. You said you thought this was the right answer. Was this the right answer, or did you end up doing something different? I am trying to solve a problem similar to yours (directing requests to a specific pod in a pool of identical pods, based on the dynamic internal state of the pod), and currently compiling a list of possible solutions.

Comment: Hi @Ely. It's been like 2 years so... I don't really remember. I think the solution was working but I ended up doing something different. But can't really remember the reasons. I think (not 100% sure) that I ended up creating a service on the fly for each "route"... then I didn't like that for obvious reasons and ended up using bare machines for the specific scenario. I know for sure that in the end we removed k8s for that module. It had the need to keep some 2 way connections open (websockets) and k8s was not playing nice with that (because pods could not be closed loosing all benefits).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can easily achieve this using Kubernetes Ingress. Here is a sample code that might help:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: YourHostName.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: Service1
            servicePort: 8000
        - path: /api
          backend:
            serviceName: Service2
            servicePort: 8080
        - path: /admin
          backend:
            serviceName: Service3
            servicePort: 80
```

Please not that the ingress rules have serviceNames and not pod names, so you will have to create services for your pods. Here is an example for a service which exposes nginx as a service in Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
```

Comment: +1 for effort and welcome to SO :). But that is exactly my issue. Pods scale automatically, services are created manually. I need to target something dynamic (the pod) not something static (the service).

Comment: Haha thanks @zozo.
Even if the pods scale, the service works as a loadbalancer. Services are abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods. So if all of your pods do the same thing then this should be fine. Can you please share your pods yaml or services yaml.

Comment: Is not a "normal" setup of webpages, those are rather trivial to define. Those are sockets for a multiuser communication tool. I need to connect to an exact pod because his counterparts send data there. In a normal setup it doesn't matter where you connect. Imagine something like a chatroom for example. Each room "lives" on one pod. When everybody exits, the pod is deleted. But while someone still is connected to the room, somebody else must be able to connect to the same pod, specifically. Pods do the same thing, but the stored internal dynamic data is not identical.

Comment: So, from the external client (I keep the chat room example because is an oversimplified version of my issue but quite close logically) point of view, an user creates a room like myEpicChat.com/room, and users connect to myEpicChat.com/room (1 service). But behind it, a new pod is created specifically for that room, and all users open sockets to that specific pod. You do not load balance the traffic in this case, you route the traffic. The client doesn't know this, and it shouldn't. He connects to the service. But the service must know the exact destination.

Comment: Can we make it so when we go to `YourHostName.com/api` it goes to the root `/` path of the Service2, instead of going to `/api` path of the Service2?

Answer (score 1):

would it be feasible to create another application
that can get the path and target the pod directly via
a pattern in the naming convention? for example

${podnamePrefix+param}.${service name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local