# How to connect to the specific Kubernetes Pod selected by Ip address via ALB/ingress/service in EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, aws-application-load-balancer, kubernetes-service

In the EKS cluster, with the private subnet worker nodes, how to make a request to the specific Pod behind the ALB/Service knowing the Pod Cluster Ip or Identity?

please see the image bellow[image]

Comment: I believe this duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/65141318/12916?